# Java Mybatis result to Hashmap

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

PSQL query is returning a list of 2 values name and count.

I want to put it to a single Hashmap and return values.

the query result will be like

```
name        count
completed   2
successful  8
inprogress  1
```

I'm able to get the result in **result** variable.
But in for loop I'm getting is Integer in *entry.get("name")* so I'm not able to put to finalresult.

The final output of this function will be `Map<String, Integer>` and it will be converted into JSON response to API by the controller.

```
{
    "completed":2,
    "successful":8,
    "inprogress":1
}
```

Current Code

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> result = null;
Map<String, Integer> finalresult = new HashMap<>();
map.put("id", id);
result = sqlSession.selectList("com.class.getresult",map);
System.out.println(result);
if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    for (Map<String, Integer> entry : result) {
        finalresult.put(entry.get("name"), entry.get("count"));
    }
}
return finalresult;
```

How do I get the name of from List?

Comment: The expected output is now updated in the question. Please check

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are expecting to accumulate the returned results and group them by status (*completed, successful, in progress*).

You should then iterate over each of the `List` element `Map`(s) and group the results adding the status count if already exists.

If your input `result` looks as follows:

```java
[{in progress=2, completed=1}, {completed=1, successful=2}, {in progress=3, successful=5}]
```

```java
if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    for (Map<String, Integer> map : result) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            finalresult.compute(entry.getKey(), (k, v) -> (v == null) ? entry.getValue() : v + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
return finalresult;
```

Else if your input `result` is of the below form:

```
[{name=completed, count=1}, {name=in progress, count=2}, {name=successful, count=3}]
```

You would then need to get the map the entries to respective slots:

```
if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    for (Map<String, String> map : result) {
        finalresult.put(map.get("name"), Integer.parseInt(map.get("count")));
    }
}
return finalresult;
```

Or a just a single line statement if you are on *Java 1.8+*:

```
result.forEach(() -> finalresult.put(result.get("name"), Integer.parseInt(result.get("count"))));
```

Comment: ```for (Map<String, Integer> deviceMap : deviceCountByTenant) {
     for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : deviceMap.entrySet()) {
      logger.info("Key is {} and value is {}",entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      if("name".equals(entry.getKey())) {
       key = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
      }
      else if (key != null && "count".equals(entry.getKey())) {
       result.put(key, Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
      }
           }
     key = null;
    }``` This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the recent version of Mybatis, you can try the following:

```
@Select("SELECT name, count FROM YOUR_TABLE")
@MapKey("name")
public Map<String,Integer> getResult( Map parameters );
```

Hope the above helps you.